# Print results on command window

Tags: matlab, window, command, workspace

I have a stupid problem with a simple script written on MATLAB:

```
z=(RASIS-LASIS)/norm(RASIS-LASIS);
v=(RASIS-PSIS)/norm(RASIS-PSIS);
y=cross(z,v)/norm(cross(z,v));
x=cross(y,z);
R_pel=[x',y',z'];

O_thigh=(LE+ME)/2;
Y=(HF-O_thigh)/norm(HF-O_thigh);
u=(LE-O_thigh)/norm(LE-O_thigh);
X=cross(Y,u)/norm(cross(Y,u));
Z=cross(Y,X);
R_thigh=[X',Y',Z'];
R_j=R_pel'*R_thigh;            


ang_beta=asin(R_j(3,2))*(180/pi);
ang_alpha=-asin(R_j(1,2)/cos(ang_beta))*(180/pi);
ang_gamma=-asin(R_j(3,1)/cos(ang_beta))*(180/pi);
```

The problem is that, on the command window I insert the `RASIS`, `LASIS`, `PSIS`, `LE`, `ME`, `HF` vectors , then click enter and the variables appear on the workspace column on the right with the relative value I assigned  them; now, I run my script to make it calculate the variables `z`, `v`, `y` etc. , but the variables I want to calculate only appear on the workspace. How can I do to make them appear on the command window too, for example, in this form (if the result is a matrix):

```
ans= x x x
     x x x
     x x x
```

?

Answer (score 1):

If you leave off the `;` at the end of a line, MATLAB will display the result of that line on the command line:

```
z=(RASIS-LASIS)/norm(RASIS-LASIS)
v=(RASIS-PSIS)/norm(RASIS-PSIS)
```

A better way is to use the [`disp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html?refresh=true) function:

```
disp(z);
disp(v);
%// etc...
```

And an even better way is to produce a formatted output using [`sprintf`]:(http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)

```
sprintf('z:%10f\r\nv:%10f',z,v)
```

where `\r\n` is a new line and `%10f` will insert a float taking up exactly 10 characters and padding spaces at the front (which helps you left align your numbers. You can even specify how many decimal points you want by changing the `%10f` to `%10.3f` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly [`display`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/display.html) a variable:

```
display(ang_beta)
```

(or, suppressing the variable name, `disp(ang_beta)`).

While `sprintf` is very useful for scalar variables, it can be cumbersome for matrix display. However, using the [`format`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) function, the number format in the command window can be changed to allow for more or less precision, or to use exponents.